# How can I merge multiple matrices of different dimensions in R

Tags: r

I have these matrices of different dimensions. The `key.related.sheet` column in all matrices have some common and some uniques values. I want to match those common rows and merge all three matrices, but I also want to include unique rows as well. The result column should have `key.related.sheet`, `Sample_B` and `trace_1`,`trace_2` and `trace_3` columns only. Can someone please help me with this?

```
aa<-structure(c("S05-F13-P01:S05-F13-P01", "S05-F13-P01:S08-F10-P01", 
"S05-F13-P01:S08-F11-P01", "S05-F13-P01:S09-F66-P01", "S05-F13-P01", 
"S08-F10-P01", "S08-F11-P01", "S09-F66-P01", "1.25", "0.227", 
"-0.183", "-0.217"), .Dim = c(4L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    c("key.related.sheet", "sample_B", "trace_1")))

bb<-structure(c("S05-F13-P01:S08-F10-P01", "S05-F13-P01:S08-F11-P01", 
"S05-F13-P01:S09-F66-P01", "S05-F13-P01:S09-F67-P01", "S08-F10-P01", 
"S08-F11-P01", "S09-F66-P01", "S09-F67-P01", "0.227", "-0.183", 
"-0.217", "0.292", "Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown"
), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("key.related.sheet", 
"sample_B", "trace_2", "type")))

cc<-structure(c("S05-F13-P01:S08-F11-P01", "S05-F13-P01:S09-F66-P01", 
"S05-F13-P01:S09-F67-P01", "S05-F13-P01:S09-F68-P01", "S05-F13-P01:S09-F01-P01", 
"S08-F11-P01", "S09-F66-P01", "S09-F67-P01", "S09-F68-P01", "S09-F01-P01", 
"-0.183", "-0.217", "0.292", "-0.314", "0.0418"), .Dim = c(5L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("key.related.sheet", "sample_B", 
"trace_3")))
```

The expected output would be:

```
   key.related.sheet         sample_B      trace_1   trace_2    trace_3
 "S05-F13-P01:S05-F13-P01" "S05-F13-P01" "1.25"  
 "S05-F13-P01:S08-F10-P01" "S08-F10-P01" "0.227"      "0.227"
 "S05-F13-P01:S08-F11-P01" "S08-F11-P01" "-0.183"     "-0.183"    "-0.183"   
 "S05-F13-P01:S09-F66-P01" "S09-F66-P01" "-0.217"     "-0.217"    "-0.217"
 "S05-F13-P01:S09-F67-P01" "S09-F67-P01"              "0.292"     "0.292"
 "S05-F13-P01:S09-F68-P01" "S09-F68-P01"                          "-0.314"
 "S05-F13-P01:S09-F01-P01" "S09-F01-P01"                          "0.0418"
```

Comment: @RonakShah Please see the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two nested merges and removal of the extraneous column

```
merge(merge(aa,bb[, -4], by=c("key.related.sheet", "sample_B") ,all=TRUE), 
      cc,  by=c("key.related.sheet", "sample_B") ,all=TRUE)

        key.related.sheet    sample_B trace_1 trace_2 trace_3
1 S05-F13-P01:S05-F13-P01 S05-F13-P01    1.25    <NA>    <NA>
2 S05-F13-P01:S08-F10-P01 S08-F10-P01   0.227   0.227    <NA>
3 S05-F13-P01:S08-F11-P01 S08-F11-P01  -0.183  -0.183  -0.183
4 S05-F13-P01:S09-F66-P01 S09-F66-P01  -0.217  -0.217  -0.217
5 S05-F13-P01:S09-F67-P01 S09-F67-P01    <NA>   0.292   0.292
6 S05-F13-P01:S09-F01-P01 S09-F01-P01    <NA>    <NA>  0.0418
7 S05-F13-P01:S09-F68-P01 S09-F68-P01    <NA>    <NA>  -0.314
```

Comment: Is this something different than @Patrick's answer?

Comment: The only difference was the removal of the extraneous column. Before I did that I was getting errors. I also didn't see Patrick's until after I posted.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more scalable (and readable) to use `Reduce()` instead of nested `merge()` calls?

Comment: That's an excellent idea. I initially tried a `do.call` solution but it failed. Maybe _you_ should post a better solution? I think it has merit.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done with the combination of `Reduce` and `merge` as follows:

```
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), list(aa, bb[,-4], cc))
```

the result:

```
        key.related.sheet    sample_B trace_1 trace_2 trace_3
1 S05-F13-P01:S05-F13-P01 S05-F13-P01    1.25    <NA>    <NA>
2 S05-F13-P01:S08-F10-P01 S08-F10-P01   0.227   0.227    <NA>
3 S05-F13-P01:S08-F11-P01 S08-F11-P01  -0.183  -0.183  -0.183
4 S05-F13-P01:S09-F66-P01 S09-F66-P01  -0.217  -0.217  -0.217
5 S05-F13-P01:S09-F67-P01 S09-F67-P01    <NA>   0.292   0.292
6 S05-F13-P01:S09-F01-P01 S09-F01-P01    <NA>    <NA>  0.0418
7 S05-F13-P01:S09-F68-P01 S09-F68-P01    <NA>    <NA>  -0.314
```

Especially when you have more than three matrixes / dataframes, using `merge` with `Reduce` scales better then nested merges.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do a full join using the `merge` method from base R with `all = TRUE`.

```
> merge(merge(aa,bb,all=TRUE),cc,all=TRUE)
        key.related.sheet    sample_B trace_1 trace_2    type trace_3
1 S05-F13-P01:S05-F13-P01 S05-F13-P01    1.25    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
2 S05-F13-P01:S08-F10-P01 S08-F10-P01   0.227   0.227 Unknown    <NA>
3 S05-F13-P01:S08-F11-P01 S08-F11-P01  -0.183  -0.183 Unknown  -0.183
4 S05-F13-P01:S09-F66-P01 S09-F66-P01  -0.217  -0.217 Unknown  -0.217
5 S05-F13-P01:S09-F67-P01 S09-F67-P01    <NA>   0.292 Unknown   0.292
6 S05-F13-P01:S09-F01-P01 S09-F01-P01    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  0.0418
7 S05-F13-P01:S09-F68-P01 S09-F68-P01    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  -0.314
```

Here the merging is done w.r.t. all the common columns, i.e. `key.related.sheet` and `sample_B` - but this should be ok here, as `sample_B` depends on `key.related.sheet`?

Using `by="key.related.sheet"` you get the same output as in Adams answer using dplyr. Then the merging is done just w.r.t. `key.related.sheet` and the `sample_B` columns from the left and right join partner occur both in the result (i.e., are duplicated for your data)

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the matrices into data.frame and join them together with full_join command in dplyr package

```
library(dplyr)
for(i in c("aa","bb", "cc")) assign(i, data.frame(get(i)))
aa %>% full_join(bb, by="key.related.sheet") %>% full_join(cc,
by="key.related.sheet")

        key.related.sheet  sample_B.x trace_1  sample_B.y trace_2    type    sample_B trace_3
1 S05-F13-P01:S05-F13-P01 S05-F13-P01    1.25        <NA>    <NA>    <NA>        <NA>    <NA>
2 S05-F13-P01:S08-F10-P01 S08-F10-P01   0.227 S08-F10-P01   0.227 Unknown        <NA>    <NA>
3 S05-F13-P01:S08-F11-P01 S08-F11-P01  -0.183 S08-F11-P01  -0.183 Unknown S08-F11-P01  -0.183
4 S05-F13-P01:S09-F66-P01 S09-F66-P01  -0.217 S09-F66-P01  -0.217 Unknown S09-F66-P01  -0.217
5 S05-F13-P01:S09-F67-P01        <NA>    <NA> S09-F67-P01   0.292 Unknown S09-F67-P01   0.292
6 S05-F13-P01:S09-F68-P01        <NA>    <NA>        <NA>    <NA>    <NA> S09-F68-P01  -0.314
7 S05-F13-P01:S09-F01-P01        <NA>    <NA>        <NA>    <NA>    <NA> S09-F01-P01  0.0418
```